# loop rows with two different tables

Tags: sql-server, for-loop, join, merge

I have a table that looks like this:

```
SELECT [Size] FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblSize]
```

[image]

i have another table that looks like this:

```
SELECT [YearWeek] FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblYearWeek]
```

[image]

I would like to add all YearWeek rows for evry Size row like this:

[image]

I´m stuck on trying to join this ....

Comment: [`CROSS JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to make every possible combination of weeks and size, which is done using [`CROSS JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690(v=sql.105).aspx) type of join like so:

```
SELECT s.[Size], w.[YearWeek]
FROM [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblYearWeek] w
  CROSS JOIN [BI_Planning].[dbo].[tblSize] s;
-- add ordering if it matters
```

Comment: Quick and helpful answer, Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help out. :)